# Meaning of three colon in docker ps ports output

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried to run `docker-compose up -d` with two identical docker-compose.yml file in two different servers. The problem is that I can not connect to my containers in one of the servers. I don't have an idea what is wrong with configurations or anything else. The only thing that is different for me is the output of `docker ps` command in two servers:

- **0.0.0.0:8124->8123/tcp,:::8124->8123/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp,:::9001->9000/tcp, 9009/tcp**
- **0.0.0.0:8124->8123/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9000/tcp, 9009/tcp**

The connection timed out for the second one.

Comment: `0.0.0.0:8124->8123/tcp` means that IPv4 traffic on port 8124 is routed. `:::8124->8123/tcp` means that IPv6 traffic on port 8124 is routed.

Comment: Thank you! Could it be related to my problem?

Comment: I don't know - which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer. But if your requests use IPv6 addressing, then I would think that it might be the cause.